# Access form VBA ComboBox click event

Tags: vba, combobox, onclick

I have Access form with comboboxes, textboxes and buttons. In the comboboxes I have the LimitToList property set to false, because in some situations I need to add some texto, and because of that, I need to validate the content of the comboxes and I'm using the OnClick event.
However if I change the text in the combobox and the click on the "Exit" or "New" button, it fires the OnClick event.
I would like to know if it's possible to the OnClick event only fires when I really click on a line of the combobox or press the Enter key, instead of firing when I click other button after changing the texto of the combobox.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can set your validation on update property of combo box. So whenever you change your combo box content it automatically checks for the validation.

Comment: It's the opposite. I want to validate the combobox content only when I click it or when I press the Enter, and not when I update the content.

Comment: @Fireblade then write your code on enter event of combo box.